# Advice on iPhone App needing to connect to remote MySQL

Tags: ios, mysql

My App needs to connect to and grab data from a MySQL database sitting on a server.  I've successfully interfaced with ***local*** SQLITE databases in my Apps, but this is the first time I've had to interface with a ***remote*** MySQL database.

I understand this process involves:

1. the iPhone App sending this request to the server
2. some sort of API gets executed and **it** does the actual "talking" to the Database on the server, and then it returns the query results as XML (or JSON.)
3. the iPhone then parses the returned information and uses it however it needs to.

What I need help with is step # 2 - the API.  I don't know PHP, I don't know PERL - do I really have to learn one of these just to write an API?  I thought that this iphone-to-remote-MySQL task would be so commonplace that such API's would already be out there, available freely - but I'm not really seeing anything.

I know Objective-C really well - but should I be using XML or JSON for this? Should I be learning PERL or PHP?

Any tips or advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give you a definite answer without knowing more precisely what you are looking at, but it sounds like your web service/API part should be quite light. In this case, it should be quite easy to write it in any language. If you know Objective-C well, it should be very easy to pick up some PHP or Ruby.

You mention PHP and Perl. The good thing I see with PHP is that it's available on any hosting service. For instance, [with PHP you can make MySQL queries in a few lines of code](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php_3.htm).

Otherwise, if the web service lives on a machine that you own or if you have more flexibility, it might be easier to write something using Ruby and a small framework like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com).

Regarding using XML or JSON to serialize the data, this will depend on what type of data your API returns. Generally, JSON will be much simpler and the support is good on both side:
- With Ruby, you can see how easy it is to use JSON here: http://flori.github.com/json/
- With Objective-C, you would use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) available starting with iOS5.

Comment: thanks for the PHP tutorial link! I already used the code from there and got a basic PHP query working against my MySQL database. The PHP does a simple "SELECT * FROM myTable" command and returns everything from my database, displaying the results as an HTML table. So is THAT considered a Web-Service? Did I just write my first API? :-)  If so, how do I now invoke it from within my iPhone App? How do I call this PHP file? Through the NSURLRequest methods? Like "requestWithURL:", etc? And how do I get it back to my App so I can parse it? Using SOAP? Any more tips you can give?

Comment: So far you have not really built an API but indeed a small web service. Don't display the results in an HTML table; actually, don't even return HTML. Make your PHP code output JSON format. Make sure the page mimetype is JSON. On your iPhone, you build a NSURLRequest with that PHP file as URL. The body of the data returned for the request will contain the JSON format file.

Comment: Ok, I have made great progress since my last post, and everything is working now. You are right: I was generating HTML tables but I needed to generate XML (I know you recommended JSON, but since I know _some_ XML I figured I would start there.) Anyway, its working great:-) My PHP file is generating an XML file which is then read and parsed by my App. I will try doing it all in JSON next. Here's a new issue though: I noticed that when I make changes in my MySQL database, those changes aren't reflected in the XML file which the PHP script generated. I have to run the PHP script again (cont.)

Comment: in order to generate a NEW version of the XML page, which reflects the latest updates to the database. So the question is: can this process be automated somehow? Or can I manually **force** the PHP file to run somehow, so as to get it to create a new up-to-date XML file?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that you use the PHP script to generate a XML file. What you want to do is the PHP script to "be" the XML file. Instead of writing to another file, just use "echo" to print your XML to the standard output.

Comment: got it! I changed the PHP code to use 'echo' to write out XML tags instead of using 'fwrite' to write the XML into a new file (which is what this one tutorial I found said to do) - and it works perfectly well. Didn't know you could do that. I thought the file to be parsed HAS to be an XML file, not a PHP file. But obviously this isn't the case. Cool. Learn something new every day. Hopefully :-) Thanks a million! This sorta opened up a whole new world for me. Being able to have you App interface with an online MySQL database takes things to a whole new level! Thanks again :-)

Comment: Note that the extension of the file doesn't really determine the file type, but rather its content. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can talk to remote MySQL server using Objective C client directly from iphone 
[as show here](http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=30)

Comment: ok, this looks interesting (thanks!) - but I gotta ask: is using this library alright with Apple in terms of them letting your App into the App Store? Only asking cause I know they're really strict about how you code stuff... Any info on this?

Comment: i don't think you will have any problem.

Comment: One issue with that is that it needs the mysql server to be exposed to the outside world and it's not very common on hosted solutions.